# Error : '(' required to start ATTLIST enumeration

Tags: xml

I have an XML document to make where I am getting the error as:
error on line 5 at column 22: '(' required to start ATTLIST enumeration

I looked into all the syntax and issues for the same but couldn't find the error on my browser. I am using Chrome Browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE bands[
  <!ELEMENT bands (band+)>
  <!ELEMENT band (name, city, logo, competition)>
  <!ATTLIST band cid #REQUIRED>
  <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST name grade ( 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | juvenile | novice ) #REQUIRED>
  <!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT logo ()>
  <!ATTLIST logo source #REQUIRED>
  <!ELEMENT competition (event, event)>
  <!ELEMENT event (tune)>
  <!ATTLIST event type (MSR|Medley) #REQUIRED>
  <!ELEMENT tune (#PCDATA)>
  <!ENTITY celtic SYSTEM "celtic.jpg" NDATA JPG>
  <!ENTITY badger SYSTEM "badger.jpg" NDATA JPG>
  <!NOTATION JPG SYSTEM "image/jpg">
]>
```

Can you please let me know the error here?

Comment: The ATTLIST isn’t valid. There’s no type defined, hence the error

Comment: Thanks @SamiKuhmonen . Your advice worked.